# Ordenar array de objetos con tallas en US

Tags: javascript, react-native

¡Buenas a todos! Tengo un array de objetos que me trae tallas en el siguiente formato.

```
0: {label: '-', value: '-', count: 2, selected: false}
1: {label: '1', value: '1', count: 28, selected: false}
2: {label: '1.5', value: '1.5', count: 10, selected: false}
3: {label: '1.5C', value: '1.5C', count: 2, selected: false}
4: {label: '1.5J', value: '1.5J', count: 2, selected: false}
5: {label: '1.5Y', value: '1.5Y', count: 2, selected: false}
6: {label: '10', value: '10', count: 930, selected: false}
7: {label: '10.5', value: '10.5', count: 622, selected: false}
8: {label: '10.5C', value: '10.5C', count: 1, selected: false}
9: {label: '10C', value: '10C', count: 1, selected: false}
10: {label: '10c', value: '10c', count: 1, selected: false}
11: {label: '11', value: '11', count: 410, selected: false}
12: {label: '11.5', value: '11.5', count: 176, selected: false}
13: {label: '11.5C', value: '11.5C', count: 4, selected: false}
14: {label: '12', value: '12', count: 175, selected: false}
15: {label: '12.5', value: '12.5', count: 26, selected: false}
16: {label: '12.5C', value: '12.5C', count: 4, selected: false}
17: {label: '12C', value: '12C', count: 1, selected: false}
18: {label: '13', value: '13', count: 86, selected: false}
19: {label: '13.5', value: '13.5', count: 12, selected: false}
20: {label: '13.5C', value: '13.5C', count: 2, selected: false}
21: {label: '13.5Y', value: '13.5Y', count: 1, selected: false}
22: {label: '13C', value: '13C', count: 2, selected: false}
23: {label: '14', value: '14', count: 52, selected: false}
24: {label: '15', value: '15', count: 7, selected: false}
25: {label: '1J', value: '1J', count: 1, selected: false}
26: {label: '1Y', value: '1Y', count: 3, selected: false}
27: {label: '2', value: '2', count: 25, selected: false}
```

Necesitaría ordenarlas de tal manera que quedarán ordenadas ejemplo:

`1 -> 1.5 -> 1.5C -> 1.5C -> 1.5J -> 1.5Y -> 2`

He probado esto

```
newOptions.sort((a, b) => a.label - b.value);
```

Y me lo ordena pero no correctamente, debido a que me queda el 2 los 1C por debajo. ¿Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedes describir la lógica del ordenamiento?

Comment: De menor a mayor tamaño, es decir las tallas más pequeñas primero

Comment: Seria `1 -> 1.5 -> 1.5C -> 1.5C -> 1.5J -> 1.5Y -> 2` asi?

Comment: Exacto, sería lo ideal.

Comment: No puedes cambiar la pregunta, menos 3 días después de haberla formulado y aun menos luego de haber obtenido 2 respuestas. Ya que dejas las respuestas como incorrectas cuando no lo eran. Solo puedes editar la pregunta para mejorarla sin cambiar el sentido de la misma y sin que afecte las respuesta (lo cual no es tu caso). Y si tu situación ha cambiado siempre puedes generar otra pregunta.

Comment: Perfecto, Yussef, así lo haré

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo primero es convertir una expresión de este tipo "1.5C"  a número

1.- Rescatar la parte númerica, usando `parseFloat`

```
let entrada="1.5C";
console.log(parseFloat(entrada)); //1.5
```

2.- Rescatar la letra usando un `replace`

```
let entrada="1.5C";
console.log(entrada.replace(parseFloat(entrada),"")); //C
```

3.- Convertir la letra en un número usando `parseInt` en base 36

```
let entrada = "C";
console.log(parseInt(entrada,36)); //12
```

**Porque en base 36?**

Porque usamos un sistema númerico que tiene los siguientes digitos: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j..... Como el hexadecimal (que llega hasta el F) pero acá llegamos hasta la `Z`. Con esto cada letra tiene asociado  un número a su transformación decimal que es correlativo

**4.- Obtener un número que representa a "1.5C"**

Multiplicamos la parte numérica por 1000 y sumamos la parte "letra"
Ejemplo:

`1500 + 12 = 1512`, esto es

- menor a `1,5D` (1513) y
- mayor que `1Z` (1036)

De esta manera obtenemos un número a partir de la "talla", el cual es comparable con otra talla

**5.- Todo en una función**

```
function GetNumber(valor){
   let numberPart = parseFloat(valor);
   let letterPart = valor.replace(numberPart,"");
   let letterNumber = letterPart? parseInt(letterPart,36): 0;
   return numberPart * 1000 + letterNumber;
 }
```

Ejemplo:

```js
let elementos =[ 
{label: '10C', value: '10C', count: 1, selected: false},
{label: '10c', value: '10c', count: 1, selected: false},
{label: '11', value: '11', count: 410, selected: false},
{label: '11.5', value: '11.5', count: 176, selected: false},

{label: '12.5C', value: '12.5C', count: 4, selected: false},
{label: '12C', value: '12C', count: 1, selected: false},
{label: '13', value: '13', count: 86, selected: false},
{label: '13.5', value: '13.5', count: 12, selected: false},
{label: '1J', value: '1J', count: 1, selected: false},
{label: '14', value: '14', count: 52, selected: false},
{label: '15', value: '15', count: 7, selected: false},
{label: '1Y', value: '1Y', count: 3, selected: false},
{label: '-', value: '-', count: 2, selected: false},
{label: '13.5C', value: '13.5C', count: 2, selected: false},
{label: '13.5Y', value: '13.5Y', count: 1, selected: false},
{label: '13C', value: '13C', count: 2, selected: false},
{label: '1', value: '1', count: 28, selected: false},
{label: '10.5C', value: '10.5C', count: 1, selected: false},
{label: '11.5C', value: '11.5C', count: 4, selected: false},
{label: '12', value: '12', count: 175, selected: false},
{label: '12.5', value: '12.5', count: 26, selected: false},
{label: '1.5J', value: '1.5J', count: 2, selected: false},
{label: '1.5Y', value: '1.5Y', count: 2, selected: false},
{label: '10', value: '10', count: 930, selected: false},
{label: '1.5', value: '1.5', count: 10, selected: false},
{label: '1.5C', value: '1.5C', count: 2, selected: false},
{label: '10.5', value: '10.5', count: 622, selected: false},

{label: '2', value: '2', count: 25, selected: false}];
 
 function GetNumber(valor){
   let numberPart = parseFloat(valor);
   let letterPart = valor.replace(numberPart,"");
   let letterNumber = letterPart? parseInt(letterPart,36): 0;
   return numberPart * 1000 + letterNumber;
 }
 
 let order_array = elementos.sort((a,b)=>GetNumber(a.label) - GetNumber(b.label));
 
 console.log(order_array)
```

Comment: Esta opción no es validad. Ya he probado y no ordena

Comment: @JadrDev No sé de qué hablas, funciona perfectamente.

Comment: @JadrDev como que no ordena a que te refieres con que no ordena?

Comment: es la mejor respuesta que te podrian haber dado, y solo tardo 1 hora en poner todos esos detalles y explicaciones teoricas.

Answer (score 1):

Sin mucha complicación, bastaría con obtener la parte numérica de los `label`:

```
let arrSort = elementos.sort((a, b) => {
    const aLabel = a.label;
    const bLabel = b.label;
    return parseFloat(aLabel) - parseFloat(bLabel);
});
```

---

**Código completo:**

```js
let elementos = [
  { label: '-', value: '-', count: 2, selected: false },
  { label: '1', value: '1', count: 28, selected: false },
  { label: '1.5', value: '1.5', count: 10, selected: false },
  { label: '1.5C', value: '1.5C', count: 2, selected: false },
  { label: '1.5J', value: '1.5J', count: 2, selected: false },
  { label: '1.5Y', value: '1.5Y', count: 2, selected: false },
  { label: '10', value: '10', count: 930, selected: false },
  { label: '10.5', value: '10.5', count: 622, selected: false },
  { label: '10.5C', value: '10.5C', count: 1, selected: false },
  { label: '10C', value: '10C', count: 1, selected: false },
  { label: '10c', value: '10c', count: 1, selected: false },
  { label: '11', value: '11', count: 410, selected: false },
  { label: '11.5', value: '11.5', count: 176, selected: false },
  { label: '11.5C', value: '11.5C', count: 4, selected: false },
  { label: '12', value: '12', count: 175, selected: false },
  { label: '12.5', value: '12.5', count: 26, selected: false },
  { label: '12.5C', value: '12.5C', count: 4, selected: false },
  { label: '12C', value: '12C', count: 1, selected: false },
  { label: '13', value: '13', count: 86, selected: false },
  { label: '13.5', value: '13.5', count: 12, selected: false },
  { label: '13.5C', value: '13.5C', count: 2, selected: false },
  { label: '13.5Y', value: '13.5Y', count: 1, selected: false },
  { label: '13C', value: '13C', count: 2, selected: false },
  { label: '14', value: '14', count: 52, selected: false },
  { label: '15', value: '15', count: 7, selected: false },
  { label: '1J', value: '1J', count: 1, selected: false },
  { label: '1Y', value: '1Y', count: 3, selected: false },
  { label: '2', value: '2', count: 25, selected: false },
];

let arrSort = elementos.sort((a, b) => {
    const aLabel = a.label;
    const bLabel = b.label;
    return parseFloat(aLabel) - parseFloat(bLabel);
});

console.log(arrSort);
```

Comment: Pero también van a llegar las tallas X, 2XL y 3Xl además S, M

Comment: Esta solución no funciona... es decir, funciona porque el array de entrada tiene las letras ordenadas, pero si en el array de entrada pones primero 1.5Y antes de 1.5J, debería el resultado tener primero 1.5J y luego 1.5Y... y no lo hace

Comment: @Pipe entiendo, gracias por la observación, saludos.

Comment: Como comenta Pipe, no funciona.

Comment: Debiste ser más específico al momento de preguntar, saludos.

Comment: @JadrDev lo que esta mal planteada es tu pregunta, en ningun lado aparece las tallas X, 2XL y 3Xl.

Comment: A mi ese detalle, me lo comentaron más tarde, por eso no puede ser mñas especifico. Fijate que lo escribo más arriba y edito el objeto.

Answer (score 0):

La solución que implementado de momento es esta, pero no queda del todo fina

```
newOptions.sort(function (a, b) {
                return a.label.localeCompare(b.label, 'en', { numeric: true });
            });
```

Answer (score -2):

La solución final ha sido está

```
// Ordenamos el arreglo de tallas
            const ORDER = ["one size", "xxs", "xs", "s", "m", "l", "xl", "xxl", "2xl", "3xl", '4xl'];
            newOptions.sort((a, b) => {
                a = a.label.toLowerCase();
                b = b.label.toLowerCase();

                let nra = parseInt(a);
                let nrb = parseInt(b);

                if (ORDER.indexOf(a) != -1) nra = NaN;
                if (ORDER.indexOf(b) != -1) nrb = NaN;

                if (nrb === 0) return 1;
                if ((nra && !nrb) || nra === 0) return -1;
                if (!nra && nrb) return 1;
                if (nra && nrb) {
                    if (nra == nrb) {
                        return a
                            .substr(("" + nra).length)
                            .localeCompare(a.substr(("" + nra).length));
                    } else {
                        return nra - nrb;
                    }
                } else {
                    return ORDER.indexOf(a) - ORDER.indexOf(b);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Aunque ahora me han pedido que primero los que no tengan letra y después lo que sí

Comment: Esta solución no funciona, además se ha puesta un array : `["one size", "xxs", "xs", .....` que no tiene ningún sentido en la pregunta original.

Comment: Esta respuesta no tiene relacion con la pregunta inicial

Comment: Realmente es la solución Arcanis, debido a que ordena lo que muestra

Comment: Lo que no entediendo es que Yussef edite la pregunte..

Comment: @JadrDev por qué marcar otra respuesta como solución si esta es la solución?